# what is max length of string to test regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following regex if I pass lenghty string to check, regex101.com showing timeout message. Is there any ideal length to test regular expresssion?

```
^(\d+[\s\r\n\t,]*){1,100}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/eC5qO7/1

Comment: This is specific to regex101, not js in general. Is there a max length - no. Is there an ideal length - depends a lot on your use case (what you are repeating, what are you matching against, where is it running, what is acceptable as wait time, etc).

Comment: Ideally, you should avoid parsing long structured input with regex. What are your requirements?

Comment: I tried in JS with same string my browser got crashed @ndn

Comment: I have text-area where user enter account numbers mixed with tab-space, space, new-line etc. I want to validate the data @stribizhev

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running a split, then making sure what is split is a number, so:

```js
var test = "123,456 789  101112 asdf";
var numbers = test.split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/);
numbers.forEach(function(n) {
    if (n % 1 !== 0) {
        alert(n + " is not an integer");
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) put `var` in front of `n` in a for-in loop to prevent it from entering the global scope . 2) use a for-loop or a forEach loop for arrays.

Comment: good points @thomas - incorporated (too much coffeescript for me...).

Answer (score 0):

The catastrophic backtracking is caused by the fact that the `[\s\r\n\t,]` character class has a `*` quantifier applied to it, and then a `+` quantifier is set to the whole group. The regex backtracks into each digit to search for optional whitespace and commas, which creates a huge number of possibilities that the engine tries before running into the "catastrophe".

Besides, there is another potential bottleneck: `\s` in the character class can also match `\r`, `\n` and `\t`. See see [*Do character classes present the same risk?*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html).

Without atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, the regex optimization is only possible by means of making one of the "separators" *obligatory*. In this case, it is clearly a comma (judging by the example string). Since you just want to validate the number of input numbers separated with commas and optional spaces, you can use a simpler regex:

```
^(?:[0-9]+\s*,\s*){1,100}$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/eC5qO7/2), it fails gracefully, and [here](https://regex101.com/r/eC5qO7/3) it matches the string OK.

If a comma at the end is optional, use

```
^(?:\d+\s*,\s*){1,99}\d+,?\s*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC5qO7/7)

Also note you do not need the `i` modifier, as there are no letters in the pattern.

Comment: `[\s\r\n\t]` is redundant, but it won't cause performance problems, like `(?:\s|\r|\n|\t)` would.  The regex was failing because of the anchors (there are more than 100 comma-separated numbers), and it was timing out because the `*` made the separators optional.  Change that to `+` and get rid of the anchors, and it works fine.

Comment: I also thought that way about the optional quantifier. Do you want to say that backtracking occurred due to actually trying to use `\d+[\s...]*\d+[\s...]*...`? Anyway, `[\s\t\r\n]` is still an issue, see [Do character classes present the same risk?](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html).

Comment: That article seems to agree with me: redundant elements in a character class do not affect performance.  And yes, I'm saying the `*` quantifier forces the regex engine to look for separators between every pair of digits, resulting in a virtually infinite number of paths it has to try.  It's a violation of one of my favorite rules of thumb: *never use `*` when `+` is what you mean*.

Comment: @venkat7668: What do you think of my approach? Does it work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev: From the article `A character class constitutes a solid block, an atomic token. Once it matches a character, you don't backtrack into it to try different ways to make it match. When you give it up, you give it up.` So there is no issue with the character class (it is syntactically redundant, though).

Comment: @nhahtdh: so, it is fine to use `[\d\w_]+` with all regex engines? :) Just poor style with no impact on performance?

Comment: @stribizhev: It doesn't impact the time complexity (still O(n) where n is length of the string). Actual performance depends on the implementation.